# Unable to boot into Ubuntu after partitioning disk in Windows

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, bootloader, ubuntu-18.04

I have a laptop dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.10. After merging 30GB into drive C in Windows using Aomei, my laptop was unable to boot into Ubuntu. It showed a black screen with Grub command line. I was able to boot into Windows by exiting the command line. How can I restore Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Try following this tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

The main steps are booting from a Ubuntu CD and selecting "boot repair", then running the recommended repair.

One thing to keep in mind is that this tutorial is not for installs which were performed from within windows. If you installed Ubuntu from inside Windows, follow this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReinstallWindowsWithoutLosingUbuntu, and follow the second procedure, which helps you migrate Ubuntu outside of Windows.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SuperUser! Could you elaborate on the steps to take to solve the asker's problem? Right now, if the tutorial you link to happens to be deleted, your answer would become unclear. Please [edit your answer](https://superuser.com/posts/1409286/edit) to add detailed instructions. Thank you!